# TypeError: crop() takes from one to two positional arguments but three were given

Tags: python, numpy, python-imaging-library, opencv

I've been working with numpy, PIL, and OpenCV to create a face detection and processing system. What I'm trying to do is crop around the bounding boxes (for further processing that I haven't written yet), so I wrote the following:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image 
def main():
    #Creates a camera object
    vidCapture = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
    while 1:
        faceDetector = FaceDetector()
        #stores the current frame into the frame variable
        ret, frame = vidCapture.read()
        #detects any faces and draws bounding boxes around them
        img = faceDetector.find_any_faces(frame)
        processing = Processing()
        #crops everything around the bounding boxes for the faces
        processing.mask(frame, faceDetector.getPoint1(), faceDetector.getPoint2())

class Processing():

    #masks around the bounding boxes for the face
    def mask(self, image, p1, p2):
        #creates a numpy array from the image
        arrimg = np.array(image)
        #creates a PIL Image from the np array
        img = Image.fromarray(arrimg)

        #crops around each bounding box
        cropped_image = img.crop(p1, p2)
        return cropped_image
```

This throws a TypeError with the message: "crop() takes from 1 to 2 positional arguments but 3 were given". From what I could find, those usually come from not including `self` as a parameter for a method, but I include mine in the code. If anyone could help, that'd be great!

Comment: Please provide the entire error message, as well as a [mcve].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`img.crop()`](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/3.1.x/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.Image.crop) takes a single tuple as a parameter (the second one is the `self` that is already added). When you pass 2, that ends up as three arguments, which gives you an error:

> Image.crop(box=None)
>
> Returns a rectangular region from this image. The box is a 4-tuple defining the left, upper, right, and lower pixel coordinate.
>
> Parameters:    box – The crop rectangle, as a (left, upper, right, lower)-tuple.

You could add your tuples together to make one 4-element tuple:

```
img.crop(p1 + p2)
```

or spread them:

```
img.crop((*p1, *p2))
```